# How to get world-space coordinate of a point in SDF function?

Tags: math, rendering

How can a world-space coordinate of a point in Signed Distance Field be obtained?

Example: Let there be a Signed Distance Field function of e.g. a cone sitting on top of a box. Assuming I perform transformations on the cone such as scaling, translation and rotation, how can I get the world-space coordinate of e.g. the tip of the cone?

When using polygonal geometry, I would query the world-space position of the  vertex that represents the tip of the cone (after performing all transformations to the polygonal model). However, when using SDFs, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect a sharp corner in the SDF?

Comment: @NicoSchertler No, I wrote it only as an example. I would like to compute global position of arbitrary point. Let's say there is a box function. First I rotate it, then I move it. How can I apply these two transformations to the 3D point representing its center so that I obtain the global position of the box?

Comment: Just apply the transformations to the point. The SDF has nothing to do with this.